# Need help in getting count on single column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need get count on single column from two tables.

Code snippet

```
select 
    ((select count(Gender) from tableA) +
     (select Count(Gender) from tableB)) as Total Count

select 
    ((select Sum(Case when Gender = M then 1 else 0) from tableA) +    
     (select Sum(Case when Gender = M then 1 else 0) from tableB)) as Male Count

select 
    ((select Sum(Case when Gender = F then 1 else 0) from tableA) +    
     (select Sum(Case when Gender = F then 1 else 0) from tableB)) as Female Count
```

1. With these code snippets, I am able to get results as 3 rowsets. Is there any way to get all three counts in one single rowset with three columns (Totalcount, Male count, Female  count)?
2. Other scenario, I need to get count of same columns in the same stored procedure based on different if else conditions. Is there a way to get these counts instead of repeating the same code for every condition?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can try to UNION these two tables and apply aggregation.

```
SELECT COUNT(GENDER),SUM(CASE WHEN X.GENDER='MALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS MALE_COUNT,
  SUM(CASE WHEN X.GENDER='FEMALE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)AS FEMALE_COUNT
 FROM
(
  select gender from tablea
  union all
  select gender from tableb  
)AS X
```

Comment: I tried with cross join and its coming.will give  a try with this approach

Comment: @Sergey- Thanks for the suggestion. Even this approach works and it saved lines of code.Please let me know if there is anything we can do to get count instead of repeating same lines of code to get count  for different conditions with in stored procedure

Comment: Whitespace is free you know

Comment: @AMDI, it is quite difficult to give general advices. Could you please show an example what exactly you want to achieve